# Installing tar.gz packages in Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

How to install tar.gz packages in kali linux? i use the current version latest kali linux 2.0 in vmware. I tried may mays but could not figure.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail, such as the methods you have attempted? Also, a similar question on Stack Exchange about Debian (from which Kali derives): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37625/how-to-install-tarball-packages-on-a-debian-based-distribution

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way is to unpack the tar.gz file in a system and search for the make file or the install.sh then run in the same folder with the terminal

```
chmod +x install.sh
./install.sh
```

That will probably install your application.
If you find a makefile in it then type

```
make install
```

Check it out and tell if it's helpful